# Cloud Function to export new documents from Firestore to GCP bucket

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to write a cloud function to export only the new documents getting added to my 'reviews' sub-collection. The trigger for this cloud function is: Cloud Firestore. However, my cloud function deployment fails through the console. Could someone please help me understand what's wrong with my cloud function?

Error message:

```
Deployment failure:

Build failed: /workspace/index.js:26
    }
    ^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at new Script (vm.js:83:7)
    at checkScriptSyntax (internal/bootstrap/node.js:620:5)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:280:11)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3); Error ID: d984e68f
```

Cloud function code:

```
const firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const client = new firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient();

const bucket = 'gs://bucket_name'
exports.scheduledFirestoreBackup = (event, context) => {
  const databaseName = client.databasePath(
   // process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
   "fs124",
    '(default)'
  );
return client
    .exportDocuments({
      name: databaseName,
      outputUriPrefix: bucket,
      collectionIds: ['reviews'],
    })
    .onSnapshot()
    .then(snap => {
        snap.forEach(doc => {
      const response = doc.data();
      console.log(doc.data());
      return response;
    }
    
});
```

Console snippet:
[image]

Comment: Could you edit the question with what exactly happens when you try to deploy? (e.g. you get an error message)

Comment: Yes, here is the error message @RafaelAlmeida: Deployment failure:

Build failed: /workspace/index.js:26
    }
    ^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at new Script (vm.js:83:7)
    at checkScriptSyntax (internal/bootstrap/node.js:620:5)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:280:11)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3); Error ID: d984e68f

Answer (score 1):

The message you are getting, `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` is pretty clear.  You are missing the closing curly bracket`}` and parenthesis`)` of `then()`. It should look something like this:

```
const firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const client = new firestore.v1.FirestoreAdminClient();

const bucket = 'gs://bucket_name'
exports.scheduledFirestoreBackup = (event, context) => {
  const databaseName = client.databasePath(
   // process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT,
   "fs124",
    '(default)'
  );
return client
    .exportDocuments({
      name: databaseName,
      outputUriPrefix: bucket,
      collectionIds: ['reviews'],
    })
    .onSnapshot()
    .then(snap => {
        snap.forEach(doc => {
      const response = doc.data();
      console.log(doc.data());
      return response;
        }); 
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting my careless mistake! I redeployed the function but its throwing a new error this time. I don't think it has got anything to do with syntax error. Error Msg: status: {
   code: 13    
   message: "Failed to configure trigger providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.write@firestore.googleapis.com (__gcf__.asia-east2.test_firestore_trigger)"    
  }

Comment: The error is about the trigger of your function. Try changing your trigger by specifying the document path as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore#specifying_the_document_path) maybe would make it work?

Comment: As your initial issue is resolved, I would recommend you to open a new question about this issue as it is different.